# $\int e^{\cos(x)} \cos(nx)\ dx$ using the residue theorem

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to evaluate the following integral using the residue theorem:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{ \cos(\theta)} \cos(n\theta) d\theta$$

I have already evaluated $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{-i\theta}} e^{i n\theta} d\theta$ using the residue theorem by making the substitution $z = e^{i\theta}$ and then finding the coefficient of the $z^{-1}$ term in the Laurent series expansion. Now, however, this no longer works, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{ \cos(\theta)} \cos(n\theta) d\theta=\operatorname{Re}\left(\int_0^{2\pi} e^{ \cos(\theta)+in\theta} d\theta\right)$$
Let $z=e^{i\theta}$. Then,
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{ \cos(\theta)+in\theta} d\theta=\dfrac{1}{i}\oint_{|z|=1}\dfrac{dz}{z}e^{(z+z^{-1})/2}z^n=\dfrac{1}{i}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\dfrac{1}{2^kk!}\oint_{|z|=1}dz\dfrac{e^{z/2}}{z^{k+1-n}}$$
Use the fact that the integrand is anayltic in the unit circle when $0\leq k\leq n-1$. This will help you evaluate the integral. The last equation occurs since
$$\sum^\infty_{k=0}\dfrac{1}{2^kk!}\dfrac{e^{z/2}}{z^{k}}={e^{(z+z^{-1})/2}}=e^{z/2}e^{z^{-1}/2}=e^{z/2}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{z^{-k}}{2^kk!}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response, and thanks for the edit of my original post. I have one further question: I don't quite understand what you did in the last equality, how you got that sum.

Comment: @Suebi See my edit